# how to take average of two text box values C#

Tags: c#

I used this code but seems like it doesn't work. does any one have answer

```
    private void txtBfrLeft1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBfrRight1.Text != "" || txtBfrLeft1.Text != "")
        {
            int befrAvg1 = (Convert.(txtBfrRight1.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(txtBfrLeft1.Text)) / 2;
            txtBfrAvg1.Text = befrAvg1.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Comment: You seem to be doing an odd conversion from `double` to `int`. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
double befrAvg1 = (new []
{
    double.Parse(txtBfrRight1.Text),
    double.Parse(txtBfrLeft1.Text)
}).Average();
```

Or if you do actually want the result as an integer then this:

```
int befrAvg1 = (int)((new []
{
    double.Parse(txtBfrRight1.Text),
    double.Parse(txtBfrLeft1.Text)
}).Average());
```